# iOS: if I add UILabel to a UIView, will the view has intrinsic content size of the label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel, autolayout

As the title states, I need to have several labels in a container view, say the labels are horizontally aligned one after another, will the container view have the correct intrinsic content size, or do I have to subclass UIView and manually calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you use autolayouts this can be achieved without subclassing (it will correctly size i mean, i dont think it will calculate the intrinsic size for you either way)